# Width less than screen resolution. But still showing horizontal scroll bar. what can be the reason?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am putting my web contents inside this div tag with this style.

```
#container
{
  width:1000px;
  height:700px;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:auto;
}

<body>
    <div id="container">
        container with equal margins on window resize<br />
        <br /><br /><br />
        <b>
            width and height values set to yours 1024x768
        </b>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to display the page on 1024x768 screen resolution but it is showing a horizontal scrollbar. What is the reason?

Comment: What do you mean 'displaying horizontal bar'? I don't understand your problem?

Comment: I don't get it. What horizontal bar? I tried it, and it looks good for me. 
Please provide us maybe a screenshot or a link to the site.

Comment: You need to use a smaller value (like `960px`) so there's enough space for the vertical scrollbar etc. Also, a screenshot would be useful.

Comment: `horizontal bar` or `horizontal scrollbar`????

Comment: I am sorry. Its horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @vape. I am giving 24px for vertical scroll bar. i don't think its width will be more than that.

Comment: Well, then you'll need to post a screenshot. Because from the html and css you posted, it's difficult to figure out why you're seeing this.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal - Are you using any CSS reset? If not, I suspect you have some margins and paddings being added by the browser. Also, you have only left 22px for the vertical scrollbar. 2px is used up by the borders.

Comment: Try to: * { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

Comment: @cen: I think I wouldn't recommend an universal selector (`*`) since it would put a heavy workforce into the browser.

Comment: Just for debugging in case there is some default browser margin/padding messing up.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal if you want to make sure that horizontal scrollbar would never appear, you might want to try `html, body { overflow-x: hidden; }`

Comment: @cen: ah I see now. Sorry.

Comment: @deathlock I want to display it, with low resolution screens like 800x600. so i cant use overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: 3 users already ask for a screenshot. So if you want help, please give us the screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

reduce the height so margin can fit to screen resolution you mentioned